# Пагинация текста для webview

Tags: android, строки, pagination

Задача состоит вот в чем:

Есть большой текст (книга, типа String), он будет отображаться в webView без скрола. То есть надо разбить текст типа по страницам. Удалось вычислить количество видимых строк:

```
textLineHeight = (int) Math.ceil(textPaint.getFontMetrics(null) * lineSpacingMultiplier + lineSpacingExtra);
```

Теперь нужно весь текст, учитывая ширину поля, разбить на странички по количеству ранее вычисленных строк.

Пробовал это сделать для textView по этой статье http://joerichard.net/android/android-book-page-pagination-example/

но текст разбивается не равномерно, и бывает на пол страницы, а бывает выходит за видимую область.

Есть идея вычислять количество символов в одной строке, и уже в цикле делить на страницы, но с webview не получается это сделать. Возможно есть у кого нибудь идеи по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы намерены использовать именно **WebView**, то обратите внимание на рекомендации отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964259/how-to-split-up-epub-html-into-pages-according-to-screen-size, если же Вы собираетесь продолжить разработку Вашего приложения с использованием **TextView**,— как в примере, на который Вы сослались,— то Вам возможно поможет разобраться с возникшим вопросом проект Alex Kuiper "PageTurner": https://github.com/NightWhistler/PageTurner/blob/master/src/net/nightwhistler/pageturner/view/bookview/FixedPagesStrategy.java
Смешивать эти два подхода — труд неблагодарный.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки не добавляют знаний в Рунет.